# Basic probability - lottery type question

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

I know this might sound really basic, but my maths/stats knowledge has gone very rusty over the years... Maybe I can get a head start here.

If I ask my user to choose 5 numbers, how do I calculate the probability of them "winning"?

Here is the list of numbers they can choose from:

$${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}$$

Say they pick $${3,7,11,2,10}$$ (all numbers are unique)

What is the probability of winning the lottery?

If I increase the length of the list of numbers they can choose (from $11 to 15$, say), how will this affect the probability of ${3,7,11,2,10}$ coming up?

Comment: What exactly is winning here? Is it picking $5$ numbers that were elected at forehand? And the order of the numbers. Is that playing a part too? Finally can a number be elected/picked more than once?

Comment: Hi drhab. These are important questions - yes, the 5 numbers are selected beforehand. The order plays no part. However, you can only select a number once - the 5 selected numbers must be unique.

Comment: Add these data to your question (in an edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a win is given as $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{p}}$, where $n$ is the size of the list and $p$ is the size of the numbers that have to be chosen by the player.

PS: I have assumed that the chosen numbers are distinct.

Comment: Correct. The chosen numbers must be unique. I'm afraid I'm not 100% certain about your notation... On my calculator, I have an "nCr" button and an "nPr" button. 11P5 gives 30240, whereas 11C5 gives 462... I guess the latter is for a unique selection of numbers?

Comment: @Eamorr nCr is the number of selections of $r$ numbers out of $n$. nPr also, but then the order of the selection comes in. In that case selections $3,7$ and $7,3$ are looked at as different.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you for clairfying that. I guess in both situations, I wouldn't be able to pick {7,7,7,7,7}? Basically, I want unique numbers where order doesn't matter. I wonder is there anything else I need?